# AngularJS $emit.$on query

Tags: angularjs, emit

Plunker is here:- 
`http://plnkr.co/edit/JaEi7ftnokYhdvBn4fRh?p=preview`
I have emitted data and its available in $on() under data.name.

However, I am not able to display $scope.dumbevent1_name in UI  using {{ dumbevent1_name }}
What am I doing wrong ?

Code:-

// Code goes here

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('mycontroller', mycontroller)
.component('semantic3', { // semantic3
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: `<h6> imsemantic3</h6> <div ng-transclude></div>
              `,
    controller: semantic3Controller,          
  })
.component('semantic2', { // semantic2
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: `<h6> imsemantic2</h6> <div ng-transclude></div>
              `,
  })
.component('semantic1', { // semantic1
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: `<h6> imsemantic1</h6> <div ng-transclude></div>
              `,
  })
.component('dumbCompDisplayNames', {
    scope:true,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `<h6>h6dumb1</h6> {{$ctrl.names}}`,
    bindings:{
      names : '<' //one-way data binding
    },
    controller: dumbController,
});


function semantic3Controller($scope, $element, $attrs){
  var self = $scope;
  $scope.$on('dumbevent1', function(event, data){
    console.log(data.name); //works. received.
    self.dname = data.name;
    $scope.dumbevent1_name = data.name; //works
    // console.log($scope.dumbevent1_name); //works
    // capturename( data); //works
  }); 
    // console.log($scope.dumbevent1_name); //doesnt work.
  // function capturename(x){
  //   $scope.dumbevent1_name = x.name; 
  //   console.log($scope.dumbevent1_name); //works  
  // }

}


function dumbController($scope, $element, $attrs){
  // console.log($scope); //works. these r NOT positional injection
  // console.log($element);
  // console.log($attrs);

  $scope.$emit('dumbevent1', {name: 'namedumb1'});
}

// main controller
function mycontroller(){
  console.log('i am mycontroller');
}
```

Comment: The example is pretty confusing with the naming you chose: somecrap, imsemantic3, imsemantic2, imsemantic1, h6dumb1

Comment: dumbCompDisplayNames is a dumb component which emitted an event and I have captured that in smart component (named semantic3) inside $on() . However, I am unable to display data.name on the ui.

Comment: atleast put a comment why u r downvoting ?? what was wrong ??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one thing to note is that the example should be a [MINIMAL](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of how to reproduce the issue. Also, the code/plunkr shows a very poorly designed AngularJS app. Those are just two thoughts.

Comment: agree with @WilliamHampshire it's hard to follow. Where is the view code that is trying to display the value? It looks like you are trying to display it in the semantic3 component?

Comment: the plnkr link is mentioned in the first line.

Comment: Anyways, i fixed it here . http://plnkr.co/edit/TVZHbko9ZV2ivCugryNB?p=preview  (A different plunker)

Comment: The plunkr doesn't make it any less confusing. Please trim it down to a [minimal, understandable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time wasted on commenting repeatedly is worthwhile somehow?? If don't have time to look at the plunker don't waste time commenting. Like I said I fixed the issue.